# Как вызвать функцию с переменной из innerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, функции, angular, bind

Нашла такой пример вызова функции из innerHtml для Angular https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-innerhtml-examples . Но вот что делать, если функция содержит в себе переменную,

```
  openWindow(string) {
    alert(string);
  }
```

значение которой можно получить только в конструкторе

```
let currentString = "green";
this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
  '<button type="button" id="submitButton" (click)="openWindow()">Submit</buttn>'
);
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что он вызывает функцию 2, 4, 8 и так далее раз, это неправильное решение

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно [сделать веб-компонент](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/using-web-components-in-angular), который будет патчить [глобальный объект](https://javascript.info/global-object).

> Для примера, воспользуемся [этим веб-компонентом с гитхаба](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/ecg-line-webcomponent)

`ecg-line.webcomponent.ts`

```
const HEIGHT = 125;
const WIDTH = 275;
const INTERVAL = 30;

const CURVE_COLOR = "#22ff22";

let heartData = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let heartDataIndex = 0;
let beatDataIndex = -1;
let BANG = false;

function fillHeartData(length) {
  if (length !== heartData.length) {
    heartData = new Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      heartData[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

function fillBeatData() {
  const getValue = (idx) => idx === 0 ? Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.1
    : idx === 1 ? Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.0
    : idx === 2 ? Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.7
    : idx === 3 ? Math.random() * 0.1 - 0.05
    : idx === 4 ? Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.8
    : idx === 5 ? Math.random() * 0.1 - 0.05
    : idx === 6 ? Math.random() * 0.1 - 0.05
    : idx === 7 ? Math.random() * 0.1 + 0.15
    : 0;
  heartData[heartDataIndex] = getValue(beatDataIndex);
  beatDataIndex++;
  if (beatDataIndex > 7) {
    beatDataIndex = -1
  }
}

function fillRandomData() {
  heartData[heartDataIndex] = Math.random() * 0.05 - 0.025;
}

function updateData() {
  heartDataIndex++;
  if (heartDataIndex >= heartData.length) {
    heartDataIndex = 0;
  } else {
    heartDataIndex++;
  }
  if (beatDataIndex >= 0 || BANG) {
    fillBeatData();
    BANG = false;
  } else {
    fillRandomData();
  }
}

function ellipse(ctx, x, y, a, b) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.scale(a / b, 1);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, b, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.restore();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function EcgLine() {

  const self = Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], EcgLine);

  const height = self.hasAttribute('height') ? self.getAttribute('height') : HEIGHT;
  const width = self.hasAttribute('width') ? self.getAttribute('width') : WIDTH;

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  [canvas.height, canvas.width] = [height, width];
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const onPaint = () => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    const baseY = height / 2;
    const length = heartData.length;
    const step = (width - 5) / length;
    const yFactor = height * 0.35;
    let heartIndex = (heartDataIndex + 1) % length;
    context.strokeStyle = CURVE_COLOR;

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, baseY);
    let i = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      x = i * step;
      y = baseY - heartData[heartIndex] * yFactor;
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      heartIndex = (heartIndex + 1) % length;
    }
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = CURVE_COLOR;
    ellipse(context, x - 1, y - 1, 2, 2);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  };

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.contains(canvas)) {
      updateData();
      onPaint();
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, INTERVAL);

  fillHeartData(Math.max(100, Math.floor(width * 0.5)));

  self.appendChild(canvas);

  return self;
}

window['ecgLine'] = (callback) => callback(() => BANG = true); 

EcgLine.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
customElements.define('ecg-line', EcgLine as any);
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import "./ecg-line.webcomponent";

@Component({
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="someStaticHtmlSafe">
    </div>
  `
})
class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  someStaticHtml = '<ecg-line></ecg-line>'

  someStaticHtmlSafe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.someStaticHtml)

  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // передаем коллбек через window (globalThis)
    ecgLine((bang) => setInterval(() => bang(), 1000));
  }
}
```

Передать переменную внутрь веб-компонента можно [через аттрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), см первые три строчки веб-компонента

```
<ecg-line height="125" width="275"></ecg-line>

...

const self = Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], EcgLine);
self.hasAttribute('height') ? self.getAttribute('height') : HEIGHT;
```